# QGIS startup freeze (QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.2-2-Setup-x86.exe) Athlon XP 3200+ (SSE), Windows XP 32 bit

Tags: qgis, python, installation, windows

I have installed QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.2-2-Setup-x86.exe on my XP 32 bit computer and encountered two problems concerning Processing Plugin,

first installation gave me following message: Plugin Processing: The plugin will be disabled because it crashed QGIS during last startup.... I found here that the message is possible to fix with registry manipulation (deleting entry in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS\QGIS2\Plugins\WatchDog or via Python Console), but the Processing Plugin is not functional.

After reinstallation of QGIS freezed the QGIS at startup everytime. I found the cause is: OTBUtils.py file, which need to detect version of OTB (description of the bug http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14949).

I have tried to modify the file (set version manually). The freeze has disappeared and Qgis is launching correctly now. The Processing Plugin is ticked and seems be ok. But I´m not sure with the manipulation.

Is it possible to override the procedure this way or should I await any problems?

Part, in which was file modified:

def getInstalledVersion(runOtb=False):
    global _installedVersion
    global _installedVersionFound

```
if _installedVersionFound and not runOtb:
    return _installedVersion

if otbPath() is None:
    _installedVersionFound = False
    return None
commands = [os.path.join(otbPath(), "otbcli_Smoothing")]
progress = SilentProgress()
out = executeOtb(commands, progress, False)
for line in out:
    if "version" in line:
        _installedVersionFound = True
        _installedVersion = line.split("version")[-1].strip()
        break
return _installedVersion
```

modification of this part:

def getInstalledVersion(runOtb=False):
    global _installedVersion
    global _installedVersionFound

```
if _installedVersionFound and not runOtb:
    return _installedVersion

if otbPath() is None or otbLibPath() is None:
    _installedVersionFound = False
    _installedVersion = {"5.0.0"}

return _installedVersion
```